# Regex match complex conditions for username

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to check if string has anything else than what specified below

- it must begins from letter (either uppercase or lowercase)
- can have alphabetical characters
- can have numeric characters
- can have dashes
- can have minus sign -
- can have underscore _
- can have comas ,
- can have dots .
- length from 4 to 35 caracters no more no less

everything else should not be in this string have have

i am stuck on this:

```
preg_match('/^[\w]{4,35}$/i', $username)
```

Comment: is that all the requirements? according to the requirements, `a..............` would be valid. is this right? because adding something like no two symbols in a row is easy to add with a regex.

Comment: The `{4,35}` bit suggests a requirement you haven't explained.

Comment: Please clarify alphabetical characters. Is it only [a-zA-Z] or is it also permitted to have letters such as é/É? Does the alphabet depend on the locale, e.g. the letters which are in the French alphabet if the user is French? Or can *all* Unicode alphabeticals be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[\w]{4,35}$/i', $username)
```

OK lets see what this doesn't work :

Match the beginning of the string, followed by [a-zA-Z0-9_] at least 4 times with a maximum of 35 times. This is quite different from your requirements.

Instead what you should use :

```
/^[a-zA-Z][-,.\w]{3,34}$/
```

The case sensitivity i modifier is not needed. Also I don't think this is exactly what you want. Usually you would need to specify a minimum length which you don't. This can match "a" for example (*not a good username*)

Answer (score 7):

```
if( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_,.-]*$/', $username ))
    echo "failed\n";
```